# how to set default login asking for password again?

Tags: login, password, gui

I want to set my login screen (greeting screen or GUI) to the default setting, which asks for password befor let me login, I dont know how did I messed it out, now running saucy, it just can show me the list of desktop environments, but after I chose the environment I want, I just click and login directly, then after I login to the descktop another message pop out asking me to type my keyring password.
    I wounder if me inserted (PGP) key from previous system did that!, any how, I just want the normal default login back, any help please? step by step for a newbie

I tried System Settings --> User Accounts GUI tool, or use the passwd command

```
sudo passwd username
```

pressing "Unlock" but is not responding as all other "Unlock"s in this laptop right now nor the terminal commands change anything, they change the password in terminal but still the same exat above mentioned drama

Answer (score 0):

I found this answer by [Arthur Tan](https://askubuntu.com/users/149453/arthur-tan)  :

> Run the following command in terminal:

```
sudo gpasswd -d username nopasswdlogin
```

substitute your username for username.

It solved my problem
[You can find it here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/211084/how-do-i-get-ubuntu-to-ask-me-for-a-password-at-login-again)