# Gnome does not ask me for my password at startup

Tags: gnome, login

[Possible duplicate](https://askubuntu.com/questions/211084/how-do-i-get-ubuntu-to-ask-me-for-a-password-at-login-again)

When I installed Ubuntu 15, I set automatic logon to "yes". But now I don't want this automatic logon. I want GNOME to ask for password before entering my account. I already tried to set automatic logon off in User Settings but that does not work for me. A possible solution may be deleting my account and creating a new one, but I don't want to do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the GUI doesn't work, use a terminal **;)**

Change the configuration file `/etc/gdm/custom.conf`:

```
sudo sed -i 's/^.*AutomaticLogin/# AutomaticLogin/' /etc/gdm/custom.conf
```